# Very lost on Generalized Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am helplessly trying to figure out how to calculate generalized eigenvectors with no luck. I have the linear operator 
$$T(z_1, z_2, z_3) = (4z_2, 0, 5z_3)$$I found that the eigenvalues were $0$ and $5$ and that $$E(0,T)= \text{span}{(z_1, 0, 0)} \text{ and } \\E(5,T) = \text{span}{(0,0,z_3)}$$
I know that the $G(5,T) = \ker(T-5I)^{3}$ but I honestly have no clue how to compute that calculation!! Any help would truly be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site, in long term it is encouraged to learn typesetting with MathJax / LaTeX. I helped you with it in this instance. You can click "edit" to see how the code works in this case if you want to. Also it can be good to show any own tries if question looks like it could be homework.

Comment: It's not homework! I'm just studying for the final and the textbook doesn't explain how to compute (T-5I) but I figured it out! I was just making a dumb computation mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You have two first order eigenvectors or "real" eigenvectors. One for eigenvalue 0 and one eigenvalue 5.

When you investigate $({\bf T}-0{\bf I})^1$ you see it is spanned by $[1,0,0]$. This is $\bf T$s nullspace. The eigenvector for eigenvalue $0$.

Now if you investigate $({\bf T}-0{\bf I})^3$ you see that it's two dimensional. Any linear combination of $[1,0,0]^T, [0,1,0]^T$ is in that space.

What this mean is that there is a larger space which will still "multiply on itself" and is associated with 0.

If we investigate how what is left ($[0,1,0]^T$) is mapped, we see that: ${\bf T}[0,1,0]^T = [4,0,0]^T$. So if we include the vector $[0,1,0]^T$ in our space, then when performing multiplication with $\bf T$ it will end on the first eigenvector.

So we have two generalized eigenspaces

1. $\{[1,0,0]^T,[0,1,0]^T\}$ (for eigenvalue $0$) 
   and
2. $\{[0,0,1]^T\}$ (for eigenvalue $5$)